# Open login page and other pages on a server

Tags: node.js

My pages are running on `localhost`. But, when I transfer these pages to a web server, only the login page is working. I cannot run the other web pages on my server.

Why `localhost` setting didn't work on my server? What are the differences?

I am using nginx web server my web server folder structure is:
`/var/www/gt.gt.com.tr/app/yonetim`

My nginx configuration:

```
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name gt.gt.com.tr;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off; #ozgur
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;    
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl ; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gt.gt.com.tr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gt.gt.com.tr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = gt.gt.com.tr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name gt.gt.com.tr;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: You really need to provide way more information and maybe some configurations for someone to be able to help you with this. What Webserver are you using? How does the configuration look? How does the folder-structure of your project look both locally and on the server?

Comment: I am using nginx web server

my web server folder structure is

/var/www/gt.gt.com.tr/app/yonetim

Comment: Please edit it into your question above and also provide your nginx configuration.

Comment: So as far as I can see, you proxy pass to an application running on port 3001. What does this application do? Is it actually delivering your website? Do you see any errors? Have you checked the nginx logs (usually under /var/log/nginx) to see what might be the error?

Comment: ı use port 80.ı dont use 3001.my web site on the web server is opening port 80

Comment: Well then your static website seems to be missing in your nginx configuration. You could try setting a new location configuration beneath the one up there with something like `  location /yonetim { root /var/www/gt.gt.com.tr/app/yonetim; }. Then your website might appear under gt.gt.com.tr/yonetim or gt.gt.com.tr/yonetim/index.html.